# Perl hash output differs from Shell hash output

Tags: bash, perl, shell, hash

I am trying to do a simple sha512 hash of a string:

```
somekeyidentifier0
```

When I hash it using the `openssl` command in SHELL, I get this:

```
echo -n somekeyidentifier0 | openssl dgst -sha512
```

The result is this:

```
 0dea2e1c2897205f595ce1418dbd216821fcdfd698b74df572c77ab785b2fdda3321765f76bc10b2821165206d90ebde5e1731942d738451e12777db2b964743
```

When I hash it using the Perl shell execution methods that follow, I get this:

```
$out2 = `echo -n somekeyidentifier0 | openssl dgst -sha512`;


$out2 = system("echo -n somekeyidentifier0 | openssl dgst -sha512");
```

and the same result when using `qx`:

```
$cmd2 = "echo -n somekeyidentifier0 | openssl dgst -sha512";
$out2 = qx($cmd2);
```

the value of `$out2` is ALWAYS THIS:

```
94a58fe5e645658694c2435be368ecdda62901aaea6a7f79c8e6070dd4773c595a0c623cc36d693009b59ae95b3a6e0c992a04ddf60e9099d8d3c35352474a4a
```

Why are the values of the two hashes different?

Comment: Looks the same to me: https://gist.github.com/mcmillhj/fc7bff8393c881a5f439

Comment: I get this: 94a58fe5e645658694c2435be368ecdda62901aaea6a7f79c8e6070dd4773c595a0c623cc36d693009b59ae95b3a6e0c992a04ddf60e9099d8d3c35352474a4a
when I run:
    perl -E 'print `echo -n \"somekeyidentifier0\" | openssl dgst -sha512`'

Comment: I've seen this exact issue before on SO, but having a hard time finding the duplicate. The `echo` invoked when you use backticks doesn't support the `-n` option, so you're hashing the text `-n somekeyidentifier0`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot That would be a `/bin/bash` vs. `/bin/sh` issue on systems where `/bin/sh` is **not** bash. And this is why using `echo -n` is not recommended.

Comment: yes, but the result is the same whether you use system, qx, or backticks :(

Comment: due to the fact that the question is essentially posed in a different way I am reluctant to call it a duplicate.

Comment: It's the same issue. None of your Perl attempts are using the `bash` built-in `echo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is typically both a shell built-in and a utility found, for example, at `/bin/echo`. The command line is using the built-in, the Perl script is using the version from `/bin/echo`, and the version at `/bin/echo` treats the `-n` switch as an argument to print, not a command line switch to adjust the behavior of the program.

```
$ echo -n somekeyidentifier0 | openssl dgst -sha512
(stdin)= 0dea2e1c2897205f595ce1418dbd216821fcdfd698b74df572c77ab785b2fdda3321765f76bc10...

$ echo "-n somekeyidentifier0" | openssl dgst -sha512
(stdin)= 94a58fe5e645658694c2435be368ecdda62901aaea6a7f79c8e6070dd4773c595a0c623cc36d69...
```